# How to have method use field from desendant class in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, field, superclass

Code:

```
ClassA extends ClassBase {

 protected IntefaceA parA;
 .... }

 InterfaceA extends InterfaceBase

ClassBase {

 protected IntefaceBase parB;

 public method1() {

  parB.someMethod();
}
```

Code:

```
ClassA testClass=new ClassA();
testClass.setParA(new InterfaceA {....}; );
testClass.method1();
```

I receive null pointer exception because method metho1 uses class variable from ClassBase that used by method1 is parB. Does it possible have method1 use parA?
  If not, I need copy&paste all code of method1 from base class to descendant.

Thanks.

Comment: parA is type of parB, because InterfaceA extends InterfaceBase. So using variable from descendant class should be without problem...

Comment: And it is object of ClassA. So logical will be use variables of class ClassA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding fields is not possible in Java, only overriding methods. So what you can do is hide your `parA` / `parB` members behind a `protected virtual` getter, and access them only via the getter method. Then override the getter in `ClassA` to return `parA` instead of `parB`:

```
ClassBase {
  private IntefaceBase parB;

  protected IntefaceBase getPar() {
    return parB;
  }

  public method1() {
    getPar().someMethod();
  }
}

ClassA extends ClassBase {
  private IntefaceA parA;

  protected IntefaceBase getPar() {
    return parA;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that in Java a subclass return values can be narrowed down. I.e. `ClassA.getPar` could be declared to return `InterfaceA` instead of `InterfaceBase` if its methods are required.

Comment: @user1252434, indeed, this may be useful if the methods of `IntefaceA` are used in `ClassA`. As this was not explicitly required here, it may be better to keep the example code simple and teach one idea at a time :-)

Comment: Good point. OTOH why else would the field parA be needed? :) Anyway, my comment was meant as an additional hint, not as a criticism on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override fields in Java, i.e. you can't say, `parA` overrides `parB` in the way a method of a sub class would override a method of a base class.

What you need to do is to provide an *access method*, `getPar` for the `parB` variable, which you in `ClassA` override to return `parA`.

Then in `method1`, when you need to access `parA` you simply go through this method. Since all methods in Java are [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) the subclasses' `getPar` method will be invoked, even if called from within `ClassBase`.

```
interface InterfaceBase {
    void someMethod();
}

interface InterfaceA extends InterfaceBase {
    ...
}

class ClassA extends ClassBase {

    protected InterfaceA parA;

    @Override
    protected InterfaceA getPar() {
        return parA;
    }
}

class ClassBase {
    protected InterfaceBase parB;

    public void method1() {
        InterfaceBase parObj = getPar().someMethod();

        // Big method... no need for code duplication.
    }

    protected InterfaceBase getPar() {
        return parB;
    }
}
```

Comment: So need copy&paste all big method?

Comment: @user810430, if `method1` uses the `par`-object as an `InterfaceBase` then there's no need for code duplication. Just go through the `getPar` method as I've explained in my example.